# How to solve the initial value problem $y''+2y'+y=t+\delta(t)$ using Laplace Transform?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I need to solve the following initial value problem using Laplace transform  method:

> $$y''+2y'+y=t+\delta(t) \quad (t>-1);\quad y(-1)=0,\quad y'(-1)=1$$

where the function on the right side is Dirac Delta function. But when I take Laplace transform of the both side, there will be $y(0)$ term which is not given in the problem. So how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t=x-1$ and we have initial value problem
$$y''+2y'+y=(x-1)+\delta(x-1)~~~;~~~x>0,\quad y(0)=0,\quad y'(0)=1$$
so we have 
$${\cal L}(y)(s+1)^2=\dfrac{1}{s^2}-\dfrac1s+1+e^{-s}$$
after finding the solution
$$y(x)=(x+3)e^{-x}+(x-3)+e^{1-x}(x-1){\bf H}_1(x)$$
where ${\bf H}$ is [Heaviside Step Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeavisideStepFunction.html). Feel free to get back with substitution $x-1=t$.

Comment: I thought of this at the first time, I dont know why but I thought when I change the variable the left side of the equation also change

Comment: Yes. change in $t$ variable and $y'(t)=y'(x-1)$ with chain rule.

Comment: Ok, understood, thanks

Comment: I think there is a mistake at the final laplace transformation. y'(0) term is omitted on the left side.